# Jquery Validation Not Workng

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

usually I've had success to install Jquery validation on My HTML. BUt now, I Confuses with validation that not working well.

This the HTML script

```
 <table border="0" align="center">
           <form method="post" action="undian.php" id="FORM_UNDIAN">

          <tr> 
           <td>Nama :</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="NAMA" placeholder="Nama" class="inputs" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Email :</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email" class="inputs" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Kota  :</td>
             <td>
             <div class="ui-widget">

                 <input type="text" name="KOTA" placeholder="Kota" id="tags" class="inputs" />
             </div><!--end of ui-widget-->

              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td colspan="2" align="right"> <input type="submit" name="OKE" value="Submit" id="submit1" /></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
```

And the js script is like this

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-validate-1.10.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#FORM_UNDIAN").validate({
            rules: 
               {
                 NAMA: 
                 {
                    required: true
                 },
                 EMAIL: 
                {
                    required: true,
                    email : true
                },
                 KOTA:
                 {
                   required: true
                 }

              },
            messages: {
                NAMA: 
                {
                    required: "Nama belum terisi"
                },
                EMAIL: 
                {
                    required: "Email  belum terisi",
                    email : "Format email belum benar"
                },

               KOTA:
               {
                   required: "Kota belum dipilih"
               }

            }
        })
    });
    </script>
```

Can you help me to tell the mistake of on my script?

Im very appreciated your Answer.

Thanks

Comment: your html is invalid table cannot have form as a child

Comment: What is the exact problem? Any message prompting or in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid, [table cannot have form as a child](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE), so make the form as the parent of table

```
<form method="post" action="undian.php" id="FORM_UNDIAN">
    <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Nama :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="NAMA" placeholder="Nama" class="inputs" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email" class="inputs" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kota :</td>
            <td>
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <input type="text" name="KOTA" placeholder="Kota" id="tags" class="inputs" />
                </div>
                <!--end of ui-widget-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="OKE" value="Submit" id="submit1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d25c3/)

Look at [your html](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d25c3/2/) the input elements are not within the form element

Comment: Oh Thanks, it work.  I forgot to put the form on top of the table, thanks a Lot

Comment: @Uchsun, please come back and "accept" this answer since it solved your issue.